# Prevent sibling from being pushed using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an image, and I display a text to the right and bottom of it , as can be seen in the first snippet(view snippet in full window). Now I want to add another text, and that it will be to the top right of the image, above the other text, but it pushes the bottom text to the right. I want both texts to be relative to the image, but the last paragraph seems to be relative to the sibling.
(**Sorry about the many html tags, I'm using a css framework also)

```css
.justify-content-end {
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                        <div class="level">
                            <div class="level-left">
    
                                <div class="level-item">                                    
                                    <figure class="image is-128x128">
                                          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
                                    </figure>                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
                                    <p>Hello World</p>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And this is the snippet depicting the problem:

```css
.justify-content-start {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.justify-content-end {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#click {
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">

    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-start">
      <label class="label">
         <p id="click">Click Me!</p>
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

Had to change your structure

```
<div class=" par">
      <label class="label">
         <p id="click">Click Me!</p>
       </label>
        <p>Name Placeholder</p>
 </div>
```

Then

added this to css

```
     .main .stretch{
        align-items: stretch;
      }
     .par{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        justify-content:space-between;
      }
```

```css
.justify-content-start {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.justify-content-end {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.main .stretch {
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
}

#click {
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}

.par {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="level main">
  <div class="level-left stretch">

    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class=" par">
      <label class="label">
         <p id="click">Click Me!</p>
       </label>
      <p>Name Placeholder</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually dislike `position:absolute;` but it looks like it could be a fair use here .

```css
.justify-content-start {
  align-self: flex-start;
  min-height: 1.4em; /* keep room for the absolute child */
}

.justify-content-end {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#click {
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #click {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">

    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-start">
      <label class="label">
         <p id="click">Click Me!</p>
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work, it's just that someone already posted a solution that also worked for me, But it's really nice to see all the different approaches that can solve the same problem